# I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' any suggest?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
A1= float(input("What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if A1 == 0:
  print("The area cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit

d1= float(input("What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if d1 == 0:
  print("The distance cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit


k1= input ('What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water \n)')
if k1== 'vacuum':
   print (1)
elif k1 == 'Air':
      use (1.0005)
elif k1 == 'polystyrene':
      use (2.6)
elif k1 == 'paper':
      use (3.5)
elif k1 == 'silicon':
      use (12.0)
elif k1 == 'pyrex glass':
      use (4.7)
elif k1 == 'porcelain':
      use (6.5)
elif k1 == ' nerve membrane':
      use (7.0)
elif k1 == 'ethanol':
      use (25.0)
elif k1 == 'water':
      use (78.5)

E0=  8.85*10**-12
C1= k1* E0*A1/d1
```

Comment: You can't multiply a string by a float, what would `"foo" * 1.5` mean?

Comment: Hi Alex, posting your entire program is not really helpful for the people who want to understand your problem quickly. Read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and maybe try to edit your question, also making it clear where exactly you're getting the error.

Comment: Try using a dictionary that holds the keys of all mediums and their values.

Comment: Use a dictionary, then check for d[k1] and it can be used to compute the result.

Comment: what is `use (1.0005)`. Is `use` a function that you are calling? How does that help? `k1` is still a string. And you cannot multiple strings with a float. It has to be an integer. You can do `'water'*4` but you cannot do `'water'*4.5`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and "dirty" fix :
You can replace "use" by "k1=" in your code ...
That will set the k1 value to the one you are expecting, and the code will work.

You can still improve the coding style, as other comments suggests.

```
A1= float(input("What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if A1 == 0:
  print("The area cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit

d1= float(input("What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if d1 == 0:
  print("The distance cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit


k1= input ('What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water \n)')
if k1== 'vacuum':
   print (1)
elif k1 == 'Air':
      k1=(1.0005)
elif k1 == 'polystyrene':
      k1=(2.6)
elif k1 == 'paper':
      k1=(3.5)
elif k1 == 'silicon':
      k1=(12.0)
elif k1 == 'pyrex glass':
      k1=(4.7)
elif k1 == 'porcelain':
      k1=(6.5)
elif k1 == ' nerve membrane':
      k1=(7.0)
elif k1 == 'ethanol':
      k1=(25.0)
elif k1 == 'water':
      k1=(78.5)

E0=  8.85*10**-12
C1= k1* E0*A1/d1

print ('E0=', E0, 'C1=', C1)
```

It works, here is the result:

```
What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
5
What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
2
What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water 
)water
E0= 8.849999999999999e-12 C1= 1.7368124999999997e-09
```

For the other error i can show you a correct way of indenting here,
but I do not have the reste of your code, and it is difficult to read in the comment: so here is a try:

Indent should be 4 spaces, like below:

```
if Ceq == 'series':
    Ceq = (C1**-1 + C2**-1)**-1
elif Ceq == 'parallel':
    Ceq= C1+ C2
```

Comment: .i have this error : expected an indented block                                                                     if  Ceq == 'series':
Ceq = (C1**-1 + C2**-1)**-1
Elfe Ceq == ‘parallel:
Ceq= C1+ C2

Comment: I did not found the line of code you write in your whole code. Where is it ? Could you show us more ? and detail 
1/ What you type ?
2/Also Copy paste the full error message ?

Comment: It works, here is the result:
'What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
5
What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
2
What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water 
)water
E0= 8.849999999999999e-12 C1= 1.7368124999999997e-09'

Answer (score 0):

Convert the long if statement into a dictionary values. Then check for the key in the dictionary.

A few errors in your code:

1. You have code `use (1.0005)`. What is this and what are you intending to do with it? Did you want to assign value of `1.0005` to `k1`? If so, you need to do `k1=(1.0005)`
2. You are also multiplying `k1` with a `E0`. you cannot multiply string with a float value. You can multiply string with integers only.

I recommend making changes to your code as shown below.

Use the below code:

```
k= {'vacuum':1,
    'Air':1.0005,
    'polystyrene':2.6,
    'paper':3.5,
    'silicon':12.0,
    'pyrex glass':4.7,
    'porcelain':6.5,
    'nerve membrane':7.0,
    'ethanol':25.0,
    'water':78.5}

A1= float(input("What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if A1 == 0:
  print("The area cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit

d1= float(input("What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? \n"))
if d1 == 0:
  print("The distance cannot be zero.")
  raise SystemExit

k1= input ('What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water \n)')

if k1 in k:
    E0=  8.85 * 10 ** -12
    C1= k[k1] * E0 * A1/d1
    print ('E0 : ', E0, 'C1 : ', C1)
else:
    print ('Invalid medium entered')
```

Sample output from the code:

```
What is the value of the area of the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
2
What is the separation between the plates used in the first capacitor ? 
3
What is the medium used between the plates of first capacitor (vacuum, Air, polystyrene, paper, silicon, pyrex glass, porcelain, nerve membrane, ethanol, water 
)water
E0 :  8.849999999999999e-12 C1 :  4.6314999999999995e-10
```